# Replace text when part of condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I have an excel sheet that runs some VBA to find a cell that contains certain text and then replaces is with new text. What I want to happen is anytime in the column the program sees the word "In" it replaces the cell value with "Scheduled to work" the issue I have though is the original cell value is not only "In" it also contains a time that is dynamic. Is there a way I can still replace the cells that contain "If" and different times? I have the code written below but I do not know how to alter it to cells that contain "In" as well as a changing time.

Thanks!

Example of what I want:

Current cell: "In - 12:30", "In - 11:45", etc.
Future cell: "Scheduled to work"

```
ws.Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.replace What:="In", Replacement:="Scheduled to work", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=Falseenter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is to replace both the word and the time for the string 'Scheduled To Work'?

If that's the case, try adding a wildcard to your sub like so:

```
ws.Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.replace What:="In*", Replacement:="Scheduled to work", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted thanks so much no idea it was so easy lol